# Deploying using Truffle unbox

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-contract

The following code is taken from truffle unbox

```
      initContract: function() {
        $.getJSON("adding.json", function(addingdappfrontend) {

          App.contracts.Add = TruffleContract(addingdappfrontend);

          // we have to set provideer

            App.contracts.Add.setProvider(App.web3Provider);

adding.json is my json file which is build directory 
addingdappfrontend is the name of the folder where my code is written
```

1)Why are we sending adding.json inside $.get json

2)We have never used the adding.json in your ui

3)what $.getjson() is your code

Answer (score 1):

You're basically using $.getJSON to retrieve the ABI code from your JSON file, this will allow Truffle to initiate the contract respectively and define its functions.

Each JSON file is different from the other, several factors (different functions, compiled address, etc.)